# Get & show realtime data from external REST api

Tags: angular, rest, angular8

I'm trying to implement a frontend web platform using Angular 8. My goal is to be able to fetch data continuously in realtime from a REST web-service that is not on the same server. On each new data that can be retrieved from the WS, I want it to be visible on my frontend platform, at least in the console.

If possible, I would avoid refreshing each X seconds, I find it very heavy as I have too much data to retrieve from the server.

Consider that I can't configure that web service giving me the data.

What I did so far

In my Angular project :

**todo.service.ts**

```
export class TodoService {
  todosUrl =  '***urloftodo***';
  todosLimit = ''; // '?_limit=5';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Get Todos
  getTodos(): Observable<Todo[]> {
    return this.http.get<Todo[]>(`${this.todosUrl}${this.todosLimit}`);
  }
}
```

**todo.component.ts**

```
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit {
  todos: Todo[];
  obslist: Subscription;

  constructor(private todoService: TodoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.obslist = this.todoService.getTodos().subscribe(todos => {
      console.log(todos);
    });
}
```

In my frontend, when I look at the console, there is no new data prompted despite some additional data added serverside (verified through a browser/postman).

I heard a lot about observables and websocket, but I don't know which way I have to search. I'm a bit lost !

Comment: ngOnInit will only fire once.  You can try using a setTimeout and making the call every x milliseconds (say 500) until you hit todolimit

Comment: Just so you know, `this.http.get<Todo[]>()` is a one-shot request.
If your WS does provide a way to use websockets, then you can look at https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket.
Otherwise, take a look at https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, `HttpClient.get` is a one-shot request.
To make that request continuously, you can use RXJS's `interval`

```js
const timer = 5000; // ms
interval(timer)
.pipe(
  mapTo(
    // Your request
  ),
  flatMap(v => v) // Flatten
)
```

I made an stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkwk4c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

If your WebService provides a way to connect websockets, look at [RXJS's websocket](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket)